# Asynctask and queue OR delay in execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask, queue

Scenario:

The user has a list of items, let's say 10 items. Each item has an Operation button, which calls an AsyncTask which makes a web call. When a call is made, the item displays a spinner during the execution of the task

Problem:

Some of the users abuse this, and press quickly more Operation buttons, quicklt one after another, executing the web calls too often. So I want to be able to somehow, execute each of the AsyncTasks one after another with a delay of 2 seconds between executions. I do not want to switch to something else from AsyncTask if possible. So basically if there are 3 Operation buttons pressed, the execution should be:

-> Operation 1 
-> 2 seconds delay
-> Operation 2
-> 2 seconds delay
-> Operation 3
-> ....

What would be the best way to do this in Android?

LE:

I have just realized something, for executing my task I ran the following code:

```
myTask = new MyTask();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
   myTask.execute();
}
```

Well, I've been using this code for a lot of time now, knowing that after honeycomb the tasks were not executed in parallel anymore without using an Executor. So it seems that only doing a simple myTask.execute() and adding a Thread.sleep() makes my AsyncTasks execute, one after another just as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to maintain a list of the operations that needs to be performed.
on click of the button add the task in the list, call a method which check the list for the task and executes it if there is no other task is running..

in onPostExecute method call the same method to check if there is any other task / operation that needs to be performed..

It may not be the full code you require... but may give you some idea..

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean isTaskRunning =false;
    static ArrayList<CustomTask> customTaskList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

    public void onBtnClick(View view)
    {
        // create custom task with required values and actions 
        CustomTask customTask = new CustomTask();
        customTaskList.add(customTask);         

        checkAndExecuteTask();
    }


    private static void checkAndExecuteTask()
    {
        //checks if there is any task in the list and is there any other         running task
        if(customTaskList.size()>0 && !isTaskRunning) {
            new MyAsync(customTaskList.get(0)).execute();
        }
    }

    static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        CustomTask currentCustomTask;

        public MyAsync(CustomTask customTask)
        {
            currentCustomTask = customTask;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            isTaskRunning= true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            // do your stuff
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            customTaskList.remove(currentCustomTask);
            isTaskRunning =false;
            checkAndExecuteTask(); // task is completed so check for another     task and execute (if any).
        }
    }

    class CustomTask
    {
        // create class with required fields and method
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if I press 3 Operations buttons one after another, the last 2 ones will execute almost in the same time, because there will be a thread sleep of 2 seconds for the last 2 ones with a few milliseconds which took me to press the buttons...

Comment: how about using a progress dialog? Display it when the task is running.. while the progress dialog is visible on the screen.. user will not be able to touch other action buttons...when the task is completed.. dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute method..  this way there will be only one task will be running..

Comment: another option is to maintain a list of operations that needs to be performed.... on click of the button add the actions to the list.. and call a method which checks if there is already a running task. It no task is running.. it executes the operation in the array list..... on the post execute method remove the operation from the array list.. and call the same method to check if there is any other operation that needs to be executed....

Comment: Thank you your answer was working as I've tested it. But I realized something, and I've edited my question. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do this in android.
One way is to use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

What you need to do is to, create a seperate thread and run handler.postDelayed in it.

```
private void startWebCall() {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // Do your web calls here
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
               }
            }, 2000);

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

You should call above method whenever user clicks a item.

Another way that I can think of is using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

An IntentService is a service that is used for doing asynchronous tasks in background. It maintains a queue of the tasks it needs to do. It is different from the above approach in the sense that it executes these tasks in a sequential order. So when you make requests to it to make web calls it will queue them, make the first call and then after it finishes it will make the second call. So the different web calls will not execute in parallel. They will execute in a sequential order but in a different thread. Also it is a service so it can run even in the background, i.e if user closes the app.

[This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183) is a good tutorial to get start with IntentService.

AsyncTaks should be generally avoided unless the work one needs to do is quite trivial. [This](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/) blog explains its pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does indeed look like it does what I need, but I want to use the existing AsyncTask implementation. The IntentService is not needed at the moment, because the operations are simple and the interface needs to be constantly updated.